# How to add a new key pair in list of dict without modifying actual list of dict?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, filter

I have a list of dict   `commandsInWord` . I am trying to filter this list by searching for a command Name in the dicts. It gives me a list of dicts `commandinWordExists`  in which the command exists. Below is my code:

```
commandinWordExists = list(filter(lambda commandInWord: commandInWord['Name'] == command, commandsInWord))


if commandinWordExists:
   commandinWordExists[0]['Count'] = commandsInModule[command]
```

The problem here is that when I try to add a new key/value pair `Count` in the list of dict `commandinWordExists`  then this  pair gets added also in my actual list of dict   `commandsInWord`. I do not want it to get added in the actual list. 
For example if my  `commandsInWord` list of dict is :

```
[{'Ability':'Green'
'Name':'setzen'
'Status':'freigegeben'}]
```

then if look for `'setzen'` in the this list of dict then `commandinWordExists` value will be

```
[{'Ability':'Green'
    'Name':'setzen'
    'Status':'freigegeben'}]
```

Now if add a new key/value pair Count in the list of dict  `commandinWordExists` then it also modifies the original list of dict `commandsInWord` . Now both list of dict will have below value:

```
[{'Ability':'Green'
    'Name':'setzen'
    'Count' : 27
    'Status':'freigegeben'}]
```

What can be done so taht original list of dict doesnt get modify?

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding your question. Could you please explain better what is the problem? Could you please add an example of input and desired output as well?

Comment: @alec_djinn added an Example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood correctly you need to create a copy of the list.

**Ex:**

```
import copy
commandinWordExists = list(filter(lambda commandInWord: commandInWord['Name'] == command, copy.deepcopy(commandsInWord)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You **definitly** want to [read this](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Python never implicitely copies anything, so the dicts in your filtered lists are the same as the one in the "original":

```
>>> original = [{"foo": "bar"}]
>>> filtered = [item for item in original]
>>> print(id(original[0]))
140326431879528
>>> print(id(filtered[0]))
140326431879528
>>> original[0] is filtered[0]
True
>>>
```